# How to differentiate $\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)\ dy+r\int_{B(0,1)}\langle\nabla f(x+rz),z\rangle\ dz$

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, chain-rule

> How can I differentiate $\displaystyle\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)\ dy+r\int_{B(0,1)}\langle\nabla f(x+rz),z\rangle\ dz$ with respect to $r$ ?

For the second integral I apply product rule, first term is $\int_{B(0,1)}\langle\nabla f(x+rz),z\rangle\ dz$ and the second $r\int_{B(0,1)}\langle\Delta f(x+rz),z^2\rangle\ dz$ am I correct ?

How to differentiate the first one ?

on the top of this [page](http://www-m6.ma.tum.de/~brokate/pde_ws06.pdf#page=74) I have the second derivative, $\partial_{rr}U(x,r,t)$ and now I need the third.

Comment: Is this in $\mathbb R^2$? If so, take $n=2$ in the following. For the first integral, rewrite it as $\int_{B(0,1)}f (ry) \, r^n\,dy,$ and differentiate wrt $r$, proceeding at that point much as you seem to be doing for the second integral: by $\langle\Delta f,z^2\rangle,$  you mean $$\sum_{i=1}^n  {\partial^2 f\over \partial x_i^2} z_i^2?$$

Comment: @peterag  $n\ge2$ and Yes it is the usual scalar product, but the result for the second part is my claim, dont have to be correct